# Migrating Elasticsearch logs to a different cluster

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logging, elastic-stack, elk

I have an Elasticsearch deployment on Kubernetes (AKS). I'm using the official Elastic's docker images for deployments. Logs are being stored in a persistent Azure Disk. How can I migrate some of these logs to another cluster with a similar setup? Only those logs that matches a filter condition based on datetime of the logs needs to be migrated.

Comment: Have you tried reindex API ?https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reindex-upgrade-remote.html

Comment: You can use the logstash, with {input, filters, output} pipeline.

Comment: @Sahil Thanks a lot, it is working. However I'm only getting 10000 documents at a time, while the actual number of documents is more than a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [Reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reindex-upgrade-remote.html) API for achieving the same

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://oldhost:9200",
      "username": "user",
      "password": "pass"
    },
    "index": "source",
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "test": "data"
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest"
  }
}
```

**Note:**

1. Run the aforementioned command on your target instance.
2. Make sure that the source instance is whitelisted in elasticsearch.yml

   ```
     reindex.remote.whitelist: oldhost:9200
   ```
3. Run the process asynchronously using below query param

   ```
   POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
   ```

Comment: I tried it (30k docs & non-remote reindexing) & it worked for 30k documents.